# Subset using 2 dataframes of different sizes R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames of different sizes

Season: is a fixture list for Australian Rules Football
Strength: has ratings for different aspects of a team, for each team in the league

I want to create a for loop that looks at each row of Season that matches the home team column with a row in Strength and then assigns that column to a variable HOME and then do the same for AWAY

Then HOME and AWAY will be used to compute a probability and inserted in a new column for the Season data frame

But I cannot get Strength to filter by Season in the loop, this is how I tried

```
for(row in 1:nrow(Season)){
  HOME<-strength%>%
    filter(Season$HomeTeam == Strength$Team)
  Away<-strength%>%
    filter(Season$AwayTeam == Strength$Team)
}
```

I just keep receiving this error message: 
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Something like this should get you started `HOME <- Strength%>%
  filter(Strength$Team %in% Season$HomeTeam)`. Again, without looking at the data and the desired output, it'll be a speculation.

Comment: thanks deepseefan, that did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments:

```
library(dplyr)

HOME <- Strength %>% 
    filter(Strength$Team %in% Season$HomeTeam)
```